# How width of flex item affects the flex container even though there is flex-basis exists

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

How width of flex item affects even though there is flex-basis exists?

As far as I know if there is flex-basis set in flex item then width property will be ignored, but in that example/code I share it doesn't match with that theory. Items are 100px since we set as 100px with flex-basis, but that width expands the parent flex container that is what I don't understand. What can be wrong or what am I missing?

Here is the code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    *{
        box-sizing:border-box
    }
    
    div.parent {
      border: 1px solid red;
      height:150px;
      padding:2rem;
      display:flex;
      width:max-content;
    }
    
    
    div.child {
    
      border: 1px solid black;
      background:cyan;
      flex: 0 0 100px;
      width:200px
              }
    
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>The width Property</h1>
    
    
    
      <div class="parent">
    
          <div class="child">
            1
          </div>
    
    
          <div class="child">
            2
           </div>
            
    
      </div>
      
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```